# WordPress 4.4 Image Conflict with Srcset and Bxslider

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, bxslider, genesis

Our company has multiple sites utilizing Wordpress with an installation of Genesis, a custom Genesis child theme, and bxslider for image sliders.

When viewing the slider specifically on Firefox, there are appears to be a conflict with the responsiveness, we believe which is attributed to the new srcset responsive image classes in Wordpress 4.4.

Upon loading a site, for example http://brightervisiontheme.com/ only about 50 pixels of the slider image appear. Upon resizing the browser, the issue is resolved and the slider regains its normal responsive qualities and height. Also, if you open Inspect Element the size rights itself.

Testing sites that were not updated to 4.4, the issue does not appear, so we are assuming it is Bug in relation to the new installation.

But we aren't sure and can't figure out how to fix.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is an inline style set on `height` on `.bx-viewport` it will stop short of expected value. I used the following workaround to wake bx up.

**JS**

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var tgt = document.querySelector('.bx-viewport');
    tgt.removeAttribute('height');
    tgt.removeProperty('height');
}, false);
```

**CSS**

```
.bx-viewport { min-height: 90vh !important; }
```